# Generate token using crypto library

Tags: node.js, jwt, cryptojs, secret-key

I am trying to generate a secret key by running the following command in the terminal:
`node require('crypto').randomBytes(64).toString('hex')`

I am doing this on another tab while the server is running, but getting this as output:
`zsh: unknown file attribute: h`

What am I doing wrong here? TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run `node` command and press enter to go into REPL mode.
The you can enter `require('crypto').randomBytes(64).toString('hex')`.
The error is thrown because the characters after `node` are interpreted as options passed to command.

Comment: That was so silly of me, thank you so much @Damian